# DataSet и dataGridView

Tags: c#, база-данных, .net, xml, winforms

У dataGridView есть 2 свойства: DataSource, DataMember.

Если я сделаю:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
dataGridView1.DataMember = "Fields";
```

то у меня автоматически сгенерятся поля и заполнятся.

Вроде, все хорошо. Но как быть мне, если я сам хочу руками привязать поле из ds к определенному полю(уже созданному заранее) dataGridView1 ?

Это только ручками в цикле делается, в явном виде? Т.е создаю строчку и ей присваиваю значения.

Comment: Справка по GridView.  Поставить AutoGenerateColumns="False", создать свои поля. Через <%#Eval('FieldName')% > или через %#bind подвязать поля.

Comment: А GridView есть в WinForms ? У меня только DataGridView есть...

Comment: Либо Вас устраивает автоматическая генерация колонок, либо Вы ее полностью отключаете через AutoGenerateColumns и сами генерируете нужные *Columns и добавляете в коллекцию DataGridView. Конечно можно использовать оба подхода, автогенерацию и ручное исправление кодом, но можно будет потом нарваться на побочные явления.

Comment: Т.е нельзя руками выполнить бинд из DataSet к существующим колонкам?